# Emails not being sent to CC or BCC recipient in Postmaster

Tags: postmaster

I've created a parcel in Postmaster (1.2 beta, build 1.1.99.4), and I want to send a copy of the email to an admin email address (in addition to the intended recipient in the To field).

But when entering a hard-coded email address into the CC (or even BCC) field, I'm finding that the email never gets sent to that hard-coded recipient.

The email does get sent to the recipient in the To field though, and in that email, the hard-coded email address does appear in the CC field. But if I look at the email account for the email address in the CC field, no email is there, or even in the spam folder.

I've used different email addresses but the same thing happens. If I have an email address in the To field, and another in the CC or BCC field, then I'm expecting the email to be sent to two different recipients. But it appears that only one recipient is being sent the email. Can you think what I'm doing wrong here? The email service I'm using is ExpressionEngine.

Comment: Can you open up a SQL client and find the exp_postmaster_mailbox table? Find the CC and BCC columns. See if they have values in them. This is a log of all the emails sent from the system. The log will report back as whether it was actually sent, or it failed.

Comment: That's a good tip, thanks (I wondered where the log was!). The email addresses do appear in the CC or BCC fields. Further investigation has shown this to be my user error - I was getting both emails, but as I am viewing a unified mailbox in Apple Mail, I was only seeing a single email. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out if an email is sent, use the SQL table that stores the responses for all the requests - which is exp_postmaster_mailbox. You will be able to check the status to see if it was sent by the server. You can also check the email conents like the sender, recipient,  CC/BCC, and even the parsed message contents. This logs will be able to give you an idea if your email was sent.

There are no known issues with the CC/BCC fields at this time.